# T-SQL - Easier way to use stored procedure data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of stored procedures that I call all of the time. I can't change the procedures themselves due to another program that makes use of them. Most of them do NOT have outputs, but have something like this to return value:

```
SELECT Duration = dbo.fn_Duration(@intPD, @dtmStart, dtmEnd, null)
```

Currently I am taking every stored procedure and returning it into a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #ResultTable(ret float)

INSERT INTO #ResultTable
    EXEC sp_Duration @ID

SELECT @Duration = ret 
FROM #ResultTable
```

Now - because I have 13 stored procedures, I'm doing this over and over (as well as running a delete from `#ResultTable`) and then pushing this to a table as sort of a "roll up" of data. The purpose is to have 1 location reading the data at a specified interval instead of running the stored procedures over and over from multiple web pages.

I would like to do it more briefly than I am doing it (which is approximately 4 lines of code for each stored procedure. I was hoping to do it more like this:

```
INSERT INTO #FullResultsTable
    EXEC sp_Duration @ID, EXEC sp_GetID @Name, ......
```

However - that does not seem possible :(

Any ideas on how I can do this better **WITHOUT** changing the stored procedures themselves?

Comment: offtopic: but that looks like an horrible design!

Comment: you cant nest `insert exec` commands - if you populating a temp table in one proc why don't you just run `insert into exec` into the same table multiple times?

Comment: @dbajtr - Can you elaborate?  That's what I'm trying to figure out.  I'm no SQL guru AT ALL , lol.  Do you mean run 13 commands (1 for each SP) like:  Insert into MyTable |  Exec SP | Where field=xyz?  Or something like that?

Comment: Are you able to create new copies of the Procs and then change them to suit your needs (ie sp_Duration_Andrew1)?

Comment: @MarkKram - I would rather not.  There are so many SPs already and I really don't want to confuse the system.  Problem is that if there is a single calculation change I would then have to change it in multiple places.  That would be more troublesome than anything else on this system.

Answer (score 0):

You cant nest `INSERT EXEC` commands e.g.

```
INSERT INTO #Table
EXEC procedure1
EXEC procedure2
```

would just run the first on in the insert and then run the second as a stand alone command, likewise

```
INSERT INTO #Table
EXEC procedure1
UNION
EXEC procedure2
```

would error on the `UNION`

If you want all the data in one table then you can run multi `INSERT INTO EXEC` commands to populate the same table. e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #TEST1 AS
(
SELECT 1
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #TEST2 AS
(
SELECT 1
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #TEST3 AS
(
SELECT 1
)
GO

CREATE TABLE #TESTTABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO #TESTTABLE
    EXEC #TEST1
INSERT INTO #TESTTABLE
    EXEC #TEST2
INSERT INTO #TESTTABLE
    EXEC #TEST3

SELECT * FROM #TESTTABLE


DROP PROCEDURE #TEST1
DROP PROCEDURE #TEST2
DROP PROCEDURE #TEST3
DROP TABLE #TESTTABLE
```

This would return the results:

```
ID
1
1
1
```

Comment: You can't do it in one statement without multi `insert into`. Do any of the procedure return multiple columns? you would need to add more in the temp table if they did. Also check the datatype if most of `INT` but some are `VARCHAR` then you would need to change the table definition to `VARCHAR`. `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition` would suggest you are getting multiple columns though